# Improve the code to design a card flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I am trying to make this design, I have finished it, but I want to know if there is a better way to do it.

[image: This is the design]

```
SizedBox(
  width: double.infinity,
  height: 70.0,
  child: Card(
      elevation: 5,
      shape:
          RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 40.0,
              child: ListTile(
                  onTap: () {},
                  leading: Checkbox(
                    value: true,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      print('xd');
                    },
                  ),
                  title: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                            child: Row(
                          children: [Icon(Icons.car_rental), Text('Willy')],
                        )),
                        Text('CDA-123')
                      ],
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
            child: SizedBox(
                width: 40,
                height: 40,
                child: ClipOval(
                  child: Material(
                    color: Colors.orange, // button color
                    child: InkWell(
                      splashColor: Colors.green, // splash color
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Icon(Icons.edit), // icon
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
            child: SizedBox(
                width: 40,
                height: 40,
                child: ClipOval(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Material(
                      color: Colors.orange, // button color
                      child: InkWell(
                        splashColor: Colors.green, // splash color
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.delete_forever) // icon
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
          ),
        ],
      )),
);
```

I am new to flutter.As you can see, I am using a lot of height and widht, otherwise I would not have gotten the result.
And the section where the name is put does not align it correctly.
I can't think of another way to do it
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just edited it

Answer (score 1):

```
class AltCard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 5,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
      child: CheckboxListTile(
        value: true,
        onChanged: (v) {},
        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
        title: Row(
          children: [Icon(Icons.car_rental), Text('Willy')],
        ),
        subtitle: Text('CDA-123'),
        secondary: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            TrailButton(onTap: () {}, iconData: Icons.edit),
            SizedBox(width: 8),
            TrailButton(onTap: () {}, iconData: Icons.delete_forever),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TrailButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData iconData;
  final Color color, splashColor;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  TrailButton({
    @required this.iconData,
    this.color = Colors.orange,
    this.splashColor = Colors.green,
    @required this.onTap,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: color,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9000),
      child: InkWell(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9000),
        splashColor: splashColor,
        onTap: onTap,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Icon(iconData, color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```